# IOS/Objective-c: Test for null with string with length

Tags: ios, objective-c, null

I am trying to test for a null value in an object, but following code is throwing error:`NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSNull length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x3b4a2a70'.`

```
NSString *pic =item.pic;//this is the value for pic in object.  Pic is a string.
if ([pic length]) {
           //do something if pic is not null
}
```

Here is how pic is declared in item object:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *pic;
```

Would appreciate any suggestions on what could be wrong or right way to do this.

Comment: Please search before posting - http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Nsnull+length+unrecognized+selector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check `kindOfClass` of an object

```
NSString *pic =item.pic;//this is the value for pic in object.  Pic is a string.
if (![pic isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) {
           //do something if pic is not null
}
```

Comment: I think you met if{![pic isKindofClass...  With this adjustment it did the trick.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You are running into an explicit `NSNull` instance, which is used in various places in the SDK.  I see it most often when handling JSON values.  In a JSON body, if there is an explicit null value, it gets converted into `[NSNull null]`.  The error you're seeing indicates that you are sending the message `length` to an `NSNull` instance, which is invalid.

You would need to check for `NSNull` before calling length:

```
if(![pic isEqual:[NSNull null]] && [pic length] > 0) {
    // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It simply as

```
if (pic) {
    // do something if pic is not null
}
```

Your code does not work because `NSNull` doesn't have lenght, obviously.

But the real problem here is, if `pic` *is* a `NSString`, then your code will work. In this case, it is *not*, it is `NSNull`. Check the return type of `item.pic`.

Comment: I thought the whole point of string length was that if it was null it would have no length and return false...  Tried changing it and got another error: Unacceptable type of value for attribute: property = "pic"; desired type = NSString; given type = NSNull; value = <null>.'

Comment: You can call length on a nil value.  You cannot call it on an NSNull value, which is an object type that explicitly represents a null.

Answer (score 0):

Following will work nicely -

```
NSString *pic =item.pic;
if (pic) {
   if ([pic length]) {
      //Do some stuff
   }
}
```